# Mapping an array of id and fetching relevant data from an external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to map an array of id and fetch relevant data for that id from an external API in React.
Here is my code:

```
const getDetails = async () => {
      ids.map(async(id) => {
        const details = await axios.get(`url/${id}`);
        setIdDetails(details);
      });
    };
getDetails();
```

And trying to display those details in a dropdown menu like this:

```
{idDetails.map((detail) => {
     <MenuItem value={detail}>{detail.data.title}</MenuItem>
})}
```

I get the error that `idDetails.map` is not a function. Also, I tried pushing to the array instead of setting state, no luck either. I have this feeling that I am doing the whole data fetching thing wrong. What is the best practice to handle a situation like this?

Comment: You can try to add console.log(details) to your code. Your details variable may not be an array.

Comment: It is an object.

Comment: If your details variable is object, you cant use map function because map function is 
only works with arrays. try to add .data in getDetails "like : await axios.get(`url/${id}`).data " and use just {detail.title} in map function.

Comment: Not working. The function runs recursively and making the app crash.

Comment: did you use useEffect hook?

Comment: Tries it earlier but no luck/

Comment: If you are using getDetails function directly it won't work. Because when your state change, all functions will re-render again except functions which you used in useEffect hook. so, you can just try this: 
import {useEffect} from 'react';
and
useEffect(() => {
    getDetails();
  },[]);

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried. I defined the function outside useeffect and called it inside the useeeffect hook.

Comment: It should fix the render loop issue and your app shouldn't crash again

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setIdDetails([...idDetails, details]);` to push the new data into the array.

```
const [idDetails, setIdDetails] = useState([]);

const getDetails = async () => {
  ids.map(async(id) => {
    const details = await axios.get(`url/${id}`);
    setIdDetails([...idDetails, details]);
  });
};
getDetails();
```

Also, make this change to avoid data specific error

```
{(idDetails || []).map((detail) => {
     <MenuItem value={detail}>{detail?.data?.title}</MenuItem>
})}
```

Note: I am hoping that you are getting `details` as an object here `const details = await axios.get(url/${id});`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the spread part. I've already initialized the state but didn't mention it here since I assumed it is correct.
The code is still not working.

Comment: I tried to console log inside getDetails and found that the code is running inifintely.

Comment: Can you let me know what are you getting in `details` inside your getDetails function?

Comment: An object of properties like title, img, etc.

Comment: Can you also make changes to your HTML as I have shown just in the answer? And then check what is happening!

Comment: Not working. It is recursively calling the getDetails function. But not displaying the details.

Comment: May be issue with your `getDetails();` Try calling it inside the `useEffect(() => { getDetails();
 }, []);` This will call `getDetails()` only once when page loads.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: The function is triggering 22 times because I have 22 ids. But the expected data is not showing in the dropdown

Comment: I console.log the detail while mapping idDetails, it is printing the expected results but not showing in the UI. Might it be due to rendering?

Comment: Hi @Nithur, Can you please check are you getting all data in idDetails? To check that just make a watcher useEffect like => `useEffect(() => { console.log(idDetails) }, [idDetails]);`

Comment: When I go to this parent component directly, it is not triggering. But when I  redirect to this component from another component, it is triggering and I am getting all the details.